# Trying to bind "point" value to "player name"

Tags: javascript

Im making a tournament system as a way of learning webdevelopment and am trying to bind the names of the players to a point.
I want every player to start at 0 and if they win a match they get one point but cant figure out how to connect a number to "player name".
This is the javascript i have so far:

```
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var list = Array();
    var doneList;
    var listLength;

    function add_element_to_array_and_display_in_order()
    {
     list[x] = document.getElementById("player").value;
     x++;
     list.sort();
     document.getElementById("player").value = "";
     doneList = "<hr/>";
     for (var y=0; y<list.length; y++)
     {
       doneList +=  list[y] + "<br/>";
     }

     document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = doneList;
    }

    function TestIfString()
    {
    alert(doneList);
    }
```

Comment: Why won't you use dictionaries storing the player names as keys and their score as value ? Moreover, you should take a look at mvc pattern (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm), try to manage logic and render on two different functions/files

Comment: You might want to use Objects, like `let player1 = { name: "Gamora", score: 0 };` (Also note that `list.sort()` will sort alphabetically by default, not numerically.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `let v = document.getElementById("player").innerHTML;` to set this element to represent a player, so we may increment it later.

```js
let v = document.getElementById("player").innerHTML;
// Current Value
console.log(v);
// Test Incrementation
v++;
// New Value 
console.log('Incremented', v);
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = v;
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="player">0</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` refers to an element in the dom, nothing to do with any business logic involved in your program.

There are many ways to solve your problem. The easier one would be to use dictionaries (objects without having to declare a class in javascript)

```
const players = []
// assuming playerName is unique, otherwise you may add id field
players.push({playerName: "any name", score: 0})

function playerWon(playerNameToBeChanged) {
    const foundPlayers = players.filter(({playerName}) => playerName === playerNameToBeChanged)
    if(foundPlayers && foundPlayers.length > 0) {
         const index = players.indexOf(foundPlayers[0])
         foundPlayers[0].score++
         players[index]=foudnPlayers[0]
    } else {
    // throw exception or anything you need
    }
}
```

the other option would be to declare a class player:

```
class Player {
   score=0;
   name="";
   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   win() {
      this.score += 1;
   }
}

const players = [];
players.push(new Player("any name"));
```

you then can render the scores the way you want in the dom:

```js
const players = [{name: "player 1", score: 1}, {name: "player 2", score: 0}]

// you can sort players by score

const scores = document.getElementById("scores");

for(let player of players) {
  scores.innerHTML += `<p>${player.name}: ${player.score}</p>`
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="scores"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```